# Select speed difference with Subqueries in the FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have an IMDB database and I'm trying to compute average cast count on productions in each year. Problem is about speed difference on selecting from a subqueries.

My query is:

```
SELECT AVG(sub.num) 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        COUNT(production_cast.person_id) AS num, 
        production.production_year AS pyear 
    FROM production_cast 
    INNER JOIN production ON production.id = production_cast.production_id
    GROUP BY production.id) sub
GROUP BY(sub.pyear)
```

However for simplification, these are two query that the question is about:

With sub query

```
SELECT sub.num 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(production_cast.person_id) AS num, 
         production.production_year AS pyear  
     FROM production_cast 
     INNER JOIN production ON production.id = production_cast.production_id
     GROUP BY production.id) sub
```

Without sub query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(production_cast.person_id) AS num, 
    production.production_year AS pyear  
FROM production_cast 
INNER JOIN production ON production.id = production_cast.production_id
GROUP BY production.id
```

The second one have an duration less than a second, the first one is never finished. -more than 5 min-.

The EXPLAIN for the one with sub query

```
+-------------+------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| select_type | table            | type  | key                               | Extra       |
+-------------+------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
| PRIMARY     |  <derived2>      | ALL   | NULL                              | NULL        |
| DERIVED     |  production      | index | idx_Production_id_production_year | Using index |
| DERIVED     |  production_cast | ref   |  production_id                    | NULL        |
+-------------+------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

The EXPLAIN for one without subquery:

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+------------+
| select_type | table           | key                               | Extra      |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+------------+
| SIMPLE      | production      | idx_Production_id_production_year | Usingindex |
| SIMPLE      | production_cast | production_id                     | NULL       |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

What can be the reason behind this performance difference? What can be done for prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Derived: plops in temp table with no chance of indexes

Subqueries: avoid like the plague

From https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/

"to watch for is the fact derived table is going to be materialized even to execute EXPLAIN statement. So if you have done mistake in select in from clause, ie forgotten join condition you might have EXPLAIN running forever."

Comment: I created a view by `CREATE VIEW count_person_per_production AS SELECT COUNT(production_cast.person_id) AS num, production.production_year AS pyear  FROM production_cast 
INNER JOIN production ON production.id = production_cast.production_id
GROUP BY production.id;` but it is continuing to make it derived?

Comment: I would never use a view. What are they but derived anyway? A scholar on views know more such as picking up indices